# Where can I find OpenID Buttons?

Tags: graphics, openid

Yahoo offers OpenID buttons on this webpage:
http://developer.yahoo.com/openid/loginbuttons.html

I was wondering if Google / Aol and other providers have similar graphics that I can use on my webpage. If so, where can I find them? Otherwise, am I alllowed to just photoshop the logos of these companies into my own graphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) has some icons that you may be able to use. The project is distributed under the New BSD License.

Take a look at their demo page to [see the icons](http://openid-selector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html).